# find the number is with in the array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to find the closest value in an array.

```
var x=[0,1,2,3,4,5];
var pointX=1.5;

$.each(x, function() {
    if (closest == null || Math.abs(this - pointX) < Math.abs(closest - pointX)) {
        closest = this;
    }
});
```

This will return 2.

Now consider the following scenario:

```
var x=[20,21,22,23,24,25]

var pointX=1.5
```

For this case it returns 20, but I don't want it to because 1.5 is not in the range (20-25). It should instead return null in this case. How can I do this?

Comment: _"it will return 20. but it's wrong. it will return null."_ - Do you mean that you want it to return 20? Or you want it to return null?

Comment: I'm confused by the last part of the question. Are you saying it should return 20 but doesn't, and instead returns `null`? Or should it return null (because it's not within the min and max value) but is instead returning 20?

Comment: no. it will return 20. but i don't want this. i need nothing will be returned (i.e. null)

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with JQuery. I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Are the values in the array always going to be in order like your two examples?

Comment: no it will be varied. i think solution given by arun is correct.

Comment: @SivaRajini That solution appears to be dependent on the fact the array *will* be ordered, though.

Comment: yes array will be ordered in ascending order only.

Comment: @SivaRajini Ok, that contradicts your previous comment, but I guess it's just a language issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input array will always be sorted then Arun's answer is fine. Otherwise this should work for you:

```
function getClosest(x, pointX) {
    var closest = null;

    // Work out min and max
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, x);
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, x);

    // Only calculate closest if point is within array
    if (pointX >= min && pointX <= max) {    
        var i;
        // removed the each as it wasn't really necessary 
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {                         
            if (closest == null || Math.abs(x[i] - pointX) < Math.abs(closest - pointX)) {
                closest = x[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZLd2S/

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
function closest(x, pointX){
    var closest = null;

    if(pointX < x[0] || pointX > x[x.length -1]){
        return null
    }


    $.each(x, function(i,v) {
        if (closest == null || Math.abs(v - pointX) <= Math.abs(closest - pointX)) {
            closest = v;
        }
    });
    return closest;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9vvkD/2/)

Another way is to sort the array to make sure the indexes are proper

```
function closest(x, pointX){
    var closest = null, array = x.slice();

    array.sort();

    if(pointX < array[0] || pointX > array[array.length -1]){
        return null
    }

    $.each(array, function(i,v) {
        if (closest == null || Math.abs(v - pointX) <= Math.abs(closest - pointX)) {
            closest = v;
        }
    });
    return closest;
}
```

Comment: good answer, but only if the input array is sorted lowest to highest

Comment: you assume the array is sorted

Comment: @SteveClaridge that was an assumption